# New to python and having trouble figuring out why the deductions are not including the tax in the total

Tags: python, addition

I am new to programming and I am trying to write a program for the python essentials course I am in. It's on Day 1 and I am having trouble figuring out why the Total Deductions will not compute the correct amount. This is the code I wrote:

```
    print("=================DEDUCTIONS=================")

print("SSS: " + sss_contribution)
print("PhilHealth: " + philhealth_contribution)
print("Other Loan: " + housing_loan)

tax_rate = .10
tax_total = int(gross_salary)*int(tax_rate)
print("Tax: " + str(tax_total))

total_deductions = int(sss_contribution) + int(philhealth_contribution) + int(housing_loan) + int(tax_total)
print("Total Deductions: " + str(total_deductions))

net_salary = float(gross_salary) - float(total_deductions)

print("NET SALARY: " + str(net_salary))
```

I get the correct NET SALARY amount, but the Total Deductions only reflect the total for the SSS, PhilHealth, and Housing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You declared tax_rate as a float, so try:

```
tax_total = int(gross_salary)*float(tax_rate)
```

If you declared tax_rate as 5.10, doing an int(tax_rate) returns 5. Wheras doing a float(tax_rate) returns 5.1.

Here in your example you declared tax_rate as 0.10, so your tax_total becomes 0 since int(tax_rate) is 0. Thats why your tax is not included in your calculations

```
    print("=================DEDUCTIONS=================")

sss_contribution = 500
philhealth_contribution = 600
housing_loan = 500.20
gross_salary = 2000

print("SSS: " +str(sss_contribution))
print("PhilHealth: " +str(philhealth_contribution))
print("Other Loan: " +str(housing_loan))

tax_rate = .10
tax_total = int(gross_salary)*float(tax_rate)
print("Tax: " + str(tax_total))

total_deductions = int(sss_contribution) + int(philhealth_contribution) + float(housing_loan) + int(tax_total)
print("Total Deductions: " + str(total_deductions))

net_salary = float(gross_salary) - float(total_deductions)

print("NET SALARY: " + str(net_salary))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I tried using float and other variations now, it's still not reflecting it. Currently this is what I have:

`print("SSS: " + sss_contribution)
print("PhilHealth: " + philhealth_contribution)
print("Other Loan: " + housing_loan)

tax_rate = float(.10)
tax_total = float(gross_salary)*float(tax_rate)
print("Tax: " + float(tax_total))

total_deductions = float(sss_contribution) + float(philhealth_contribution) + float(housing_loan) + float(tax_total)
print("Total Deductions: " + str(total_deductions))`

Comment: I updated my answer with the changes needed for your code to work.